# Custom Table View Cells with different Layout in Apple Swift

Tags: swift

i am looking for the best solution create a TableView with different Layouts.

For Example: I need a few rows, with with a Label and a Textview, and some with a Label and a Textbox.

At the Moment i have 2 Custom Cells, and create an instance of them in my TableView function, and return the correct cell depending on my indexPath.row (this is also the key in my Array where i cant find out with type of Layout i need).

Is this the correct way do handle this?

Another Question is how to get these Values from the Textbox. Should i use the "AfterEdid" Action from TableView/Textbox and Write them into one global Array? Or is it possible to retrieve the Values easer from a Textbox/Testview inside a cell in a Table?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to define two cell prototypes in the Storyboard, each one with a different cell identifier. The in the `UITableViewDataSource`, method `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should dequeue the cell of correct type based on your application logic.

Comment: Thank you - ive done this already. Do i need a different class for each cell? Or can i create a new Instance of an Cell and just use the correct ReuseIdentifier?

I have another Question about hiding rows - normally i set the height of the Rows to 0. But if i do that and render a row the row content will be overlapping. If i select this row, only the correct content is displayed.

Is this a Swift Bug? Or is there another Possibility to hide rows?